# Using the following tree navigation script, how to make the heading trigger the drop down?

Tags: javascript, tree, navigation, drop-down-menu

We're using the following script to have a dropdown navigation:

http://www.onlinetools.org/tools/dom-tree-menu-puredom/#

However, the drop down is only triggered when the [+] or [-] is clicked. What we like to happen is for the headings themselves to trigger the dropdown. Like:

```
[+] Heading
[+] Heading 2
[+] Heading 3
```

When we click on [+] and also the word "Heading" we like the drop down list to appear like so:

```
[-] Heading
 -- Content 1
 -- Content 2
 -- Content 3
[+] Heading 2
[+] Heading 3
```

Currently, only the [+] triggers the drop down and "Heading" merely allows us to put a normal link.

Comment: Do you have *any* code so far?

Comment: Haven't placed it on our website yet. I just used exactly the same code from the website to test how it's supposed to work. So basically, the code is the one on the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linkParent:false` change to `linkParent:true`

If you change that to true I have a feeling that will allow the heading to do the linking too.

If you take a look at line 41 it sets the click handler.  The first a tag [0] is the arrow and the second a tag [1] I believe is the title

```
pde.addEvent(parentLI.getElementsByTagName('a')[0],'click',pde.showhide,false);
parentLI.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick=function(){return false;} // Safari hack
if(pde.linkParent){
    pde.addEvent(parentLI.getElementsByTagName('a')[1],'click',pde.showhide,false);
    parentLI.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].onclick=function(){return false;} // Safari hack

}
```

Hint: They also have a nice comment in the beginning of the script.

```
// boolean to make the parent link collapse the section or not 

    linkParent:false,
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't notice that note. :D